# global variable in javascript is always empty and never updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got one partial view and when I click a link in this partial view I add a hashset to the url and make ajax request and update the view;( what I'm trying is to achieve when I click back button to load again the previous partial view). The problem is that on document ready I check each second if there is change in the hashet - and it seems that each time I check the variable `recenthash` in checHash finction  is empty. What may be the reason.

```
@model  MvcBeaWeb.GroupMenu    
    <div class="lc-container-contentmenu">
         foreach (MvcBeaDAL.WebServiceBeaMenu item in Model.MenuLeft)
         {                                                  
               @Html.ActionLink(@item.SpecialWord, "ImportShow", new { menuID = @item.ID, articlegroupID = @item.ArticlegroupID })                                
         }                  
    </div>

    <script>
        var recentHash = '';
        function hashChange() {
            var page = location.hash.slice(1);
            if (page != "") {        
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: page        
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $("#importPartUpdate").html(data);
                }) 
            }
        }

        function checkHash() {
           var hash = location.hash;
            if (hash) {

                if (hash == recentHash) {
                    return;
                }
                recentHash = hash;
               hashChange();
            }
        }       

        $(function () {                
            $('.ajaxLinks a').click(function (e)
            {
                location.hash = $(this).attr('href')
                return false;
            })
            setInterval(checkHash, 1000);           

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: There's no `.ajaxLinks` in the sample - is your click function firing?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with scoping.

`var recentHash` and `recentHash` (defined on window.hash) are scoped differently.

http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/